# onmouseleave triggered when the mouse enters the space of another element, even if that space is shared with the first element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a simple javascript menu for a web page, and everything seems to work well. The function that fades the menu in (by changing the opacity of the element) is linked to an onmouseover event in the menu title element, and the functions to fade it out is linked to a onmouseleave event.

The menus partially overlap (position attribute is set to absolute, and I need that for the page design), but it isn't a problem because only one at a time is showed.

I've noticed that whenever the mouse enters the space occupied by the next menu, the onmouseleave event is triggered, fading the current menu out, even if that space is shared. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: can you post a link to a fiddle?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions require code and, where practical, a demo. We don't have enough information here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the css z Index of the faded in element